# Splitting two integer values in a cell separated by a comma using Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have this column with some cells that have two values, first value is price after discount and second value is price after discount. I need to separate these values into two cells before and after discount I have tried the following methods but neither of them works so if anyone have any suggestions how to make or how to edit the code to do it.
**Column Example:**
**Price**
row 1: 79.9,99.9
row 2: 59.9
row 3: 49.9,89.9
row 4: 59.9

**Method 1:**

```
for z in x['1Month Price']:
x['1Month Price'].split(',')
```

**Error:**

```
    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-1b04b6fed466> in <module>
----> 1 x['1_Month_bf'] = x['1Month Price'].split(',', expand = True)
      2 x.head()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5463             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5464                 return self[name]
-> 5465             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5466 
   5467     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'
```

**Method 2:**

```
    x['1_Month_bf'] = x['1Month Price'].apply(lambda z: z.split(',')[0])
x.head()
```

**Error:**

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-aa7ce98376af> in <module>
----> 1 x['1_Month_bf'] = x['1Month Price'].apply(lambda z: z.split(',')[0])
      2 x.head()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   4136             else:
   4137                 values = self.astype(object)._values
-> 4138                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   4139 
   4140         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas\_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-33-aa7ce98376af> in <lambda>(z)
----> 1 x['1_Month_bf'] = x['1Month Price'].apply(lambda z: z.split(',')[0])
      2 x.head()

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Comment: You can use method 2 with a full blown function instead of a lambda. This function can then be written to check the type of "z" before "split" and react accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df[['Price A', 'Price B']] = df['Price'].str.split(',', expand=True)`

Outcome

```
   Price       Price A  Price B
0  79.9,99.9    79.9     99.9
1       59.9    59.9     None
2  49.9,89.9    49.9     89.9
3       59.9    59.9     None
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with `str.split`. First convert each rows as string to avoid the 2nd error then split your strings then convert them as float.

```
df[['discount', 'price']] = (
    df['1Month Price'].astype(str).str.split(',', expand=True).astype(float)
)
print(df)

# Output
  1Month Price  discount  price
0    79.9,99.9      79.9   99.9
1         59.9      59.9    NaN
2    49.9,89.9      49.9   89.9
3         59.9      59.9    NaN
```